# How to convert decimal to 1's complement hexadecimal in python

Tags: python, binary, hex, decimal

I need to figure out, in python, how to convert a signed decimal to hexadecimal using 1's complement for negative values. The example results I need to get are below:

> 0 becomes 0000,
>
> 65.5 becomes 0041
>
> 200 becomes 00c8
>
> -200 becomes ff37

I can easily get the positive ones using hex(), but how do I do the conversions to get the correct values for negative numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples are wrong. With `6.55` you actually mean `65` which leads to `0x41`. `20` becomes `0x14`, not `0xc8` because that would be `200`.
The one complement for `0x20` is `0xeb` not `0x37` or `0xff37`.

To calculate the one's-complement you can use the [XOR-operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.xor). Use `0xFF` or `0xFFFF`, depending on the bit-depth of your expected data.

**16-Bit:**

```
hex(0x14 ^ 0xFFFF) -> 0xffeb

0b0000000000010100 ^
0b1111111111111111
------------------
0b1111111111101011 -> 0xffeb
```

**8-Bit:**

```
hex(0x14 ^ 0xFF)   -> 0xeb
```